# An addition to a previous question about: Diagonalizable $\mathcal A$ and finding $\mathcal S$ and $\Lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given:

$$\mathcal A=\pmatrix{-5.25&-4.125&8.25\\-15&-0.5&15\\-4.75&-0.375&7.75}$$

$det(\Lambda I-\mathcal A)=0$ gives $\lambda_1=3$, $\lambda_2=7$ and $\lambda_3=-8$.

Instead of performing the row reductions by hand, I asked Matlab to calculate the LU decomposition for each $\mathcal U$ associated with each $\lambda$ value.  Unfortunately for $\mathcal U_3$ there is an empty set for the eigenvector.  I even tried the Matlab 'cheat' ~ null(U) and that produced an empty vector.  Therefore, $\mathcal S^{-1}$ doesn't exist. This problem is driving me crazy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: Did you miss a minus or something ?

Comment: Here is Wolfram Alpha characterization - you have correct eigenvalues, but eigenvectors seems to be in order as well: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-5.25%2C-4.125%2C8.25%7D%2C%7B-15%2C-0.5%2C15%7D%2C%7B-4.75%2C-0.375%2C7.75%7D%7D

Comment: @justt~I've checked and rechecked my eigenvectors.  For $\lambda_1$ my eigenvector is $[1,0,1]^T$, for $\lambda_2$  $[0,2,1]^T$ and for $\lambda_3$  $[0,0,0]^T$.  Therefore, my $\mathcal S= \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&2&0\\1&1&0}$

Comment: You can't have a zero eigenvector. What is your $U_3$ matrix ?

Comment: @gt6989b~ thanks for the link.  wow!!

Comment: @jusst~ $\mathcal U_3=\pmatrix{15&-7.5&-15\\0&2.75&-11\\0&0&-1.5}$  gt6989b gave me a solution through wolfgramalpha, but I would really like to find out why it won't work through this method.

Comment: @Lanae: Can you try this Matlab command $[d, X, res] := numeric::eigenvectors(A):$? http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-eigenvectors.html

Comment: @Amzoti~ I was looking for the upper triangular form.  I used gt6989b's suggestion and then found in Matlab the [v,e]=eig(A) command and they both produced the same answer.  So that's what I'm running with.

Comment: Did you try that matlab command I gave you? Also, can you write out what that eig command produced. I am trying to reverse engineer what you have done to understand it.

Comment: @Lanae: Also, I did not get the $-1.5$ term in the LU, if that helps, but I worked through this and there is something wrong with this approach as far as I can tell. I would need more data, like if you can add what you got from the eig command.

Comment: @Amzoti~ [v,e]=eig(A) gave me characteristic equation $$-\lambda ^3+2\lambda +59\lambda -168=0$$  Therefore, $\lambda_1=-8$, $\lambda_2=7$ and $\lambda_3=3$.    $\nu_1=[-0.5883, -0.7845, -0.1961]$, $\nu_2=[0, 0.8944, 0.4472]$ and $\nu_3=[0.7071, 0, 0.7071]$

Comment: @Lanae: okay, so how does that compare with the integer values you are finding for the LU approach or the Wolfram result?

Comment: @Amzoti~ same as Wolfram.  LU approach gives me a $U_3$ that is above which results in a nonexistent $S^{-1}$.

Comment: That is what I am saying, WA and Matlab produced correct results. The LU approach is not going to produce correct results. Is that clear? This is correct for $S$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-5.25%2C-4.125%2C8.25%7D%2C%7B-15%2C-0.5%2C15%7D%2C%7B-4.75%2C-0.375%2C7.75%7D%7D. Why is this strangeness happening? Did you look at the condition number of this matrix (are you learning about that)?

Comment: @Amzoti~ I did see the condition number at the bottom (16?) but have no idea what that means.  I'm in a linear algebra class that is focused on engineering applications.  So its been quick and dirty learning.    You were able to help with with my transformation problems.  Would you look at my reflection and rotation of a parabolic-like function question please?